# Кастомизация TabLayout (иконки в одну строку с текстом)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-sdk, android-tablayout

Не могу понять как разместить иконки в одну строку с текстом в TabLayout как показано тут(https://m2.material.io/components/tabs#usage): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой XML-файл:

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayoutWorkExample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tabIconTint="@color/selector_tab_icon_colors"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/blue"
    app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/blue">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_summer"
        android:text="@string/Summer" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_winter"
        android:text="@string/Winter" />

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

выглядит так: [image: текущий вид в приложении]

Comment: app:tabInlineLabel="true"

Comment: да, в макете стало отображаться как нужно, но пчм то при запуске не видно